# Parsing .s2p data through an automation script to plot graphs of the various s-parameters

Tags: rf, matlab, python, s-parameters

Need to find a way to quickly decipher and plot s-parameters for tons of [.s2p](http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/genesys200801/sim/linear_sim/sparams/touchstone_file_format.htm) files in a short period of time.

In specific, I need to plot the angle of the s-parameters versus frequency and then the amplitude of the s-parameters versus frequency.

There needs to be a faster way of doing this. Any ideas of programming this in an automation script (python or MatLab is preferred).

Comment: This is just one answer that I found, and I was wondering if anyone else found a much better solution. I am open to any other solutions. :) Also, I wanted to share this knowledge with people since it is common in research and the fact that this package exists is not really advertised.

Comment: In Python, there's scikit-rf, but I haven't used it myself so can't say how complete and robust it is.

Answer (score 1):

I found this neat [MATLAB S-Parameter toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6080-s-parameter-toolbox--+-z--y--h--g--abcd--t-).

Using the SXPParse.m function we will get the data of the s-parameters in the .sNp file in terms of real and imaginary parts.

If you just want to keep it in its given [format](http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/genesys200801/sim/linear_sim/sparams/touchstone_file_format.htm), then change the function such that it return raw_data instead of data.

Using the link that gave us information of the format of the file we can no easily create automation scripts to extract the gain and phase of the s-parameters.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
DataFileName = 'cpl iso.s2p';
[freq, raw_data,data, freq_noise, data_noise, Zo] = SXPParse(DataFileName);

% interested s-parameters data
interested_data = raw_data(301:401,:); %dB and angle (degrees)
interested_freq = freq(301:401); %Hz

%Magnitude
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(interested_freq,interested_data(:,3),'-r');
hold on
plot(interested_freq,interested_data(:,5),'-b');
legend('S21','S12');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)','fontsize',12,'fontweight','b')
ylabel ('Amplitude (dB)','fontsize',12,'fontweight','b')
title ('1 - CPL, 2 - ISO','fontsize',16,'fontweight','b')
```

Comment: Here's the package I use with matlab. The s2p reader you found looks much better, but you might find these additional functions helpful. http://rf.helpingcreate.com/cgi-bin/octave.pl